# 入力した数値の単位を項目ごとに指定する方法

Tags: javascript, java, html, jquery

初めまして

プログラミングを学んでいる者です。
どうやって実現すればいいかわからないので先輩方の力を借りたいです。

実現したいこと
各項目　A,B,C　があって
Aが追加されたら数値入力の単位を0.1ずつ増減できる
Bが追加されたら数値入力の単位を0.5ずつ増減できる
Cが追加されたら数値入力の単位を1.0ずつ増減できる
というのを実現したいです。

HTML,Javascript,Jquery,Javaなどで実装できる方法がありましたらご教授ください。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 助言程度で構いません

Comment: 今の質問では「項目」や「数値入力」というのが具体的に何を示しているのかがわかりません。「追加」というのもどういうアクションなのかも不明ですし、その結果として表れる「増減」も増やすのか減らすのかの基準もわかりません。また、HTML等とか書いていますが、どのようなプログラム、つまりは、Webアプリなのかデスクトップアプリなのかそういったものもわからないです。これでは誰も答えようがありません。もう少し具体的に、どのような物が作りたいのか、そもそもの目的は何なのか(XY問題になっているかもしれないので)を質問に追加するとともに、「項目の追加」という動作や「数値入力」とは一体なんなのかを述べ見てください。

Comment: 具体的に述べることが難しい場合は、今自分で書いている途中のコードを示してみてください。それだけでも、何がしたいのかが、他の人により具体的に伝わります。

Comment: 「どうやって実現すればいいかわからない」とありますが、こちらは質問者さんのアウトプットイメージが分かりません。図などで説明されると伝わりやすくなるかと思います。